# Which nondegenerate multilinear forms exist?

Tags: linear-algebra

In this question all linear spaces are over $\mathbb{R}$.

A *$k$-linear form* on a linear space $V$ is a map $V^k\to \mathbb{R}$ that is linear in each of its $k$ arguments. Such a form doesn't need to be alternating.
$k$-linear form $f$ is *nondegenerate* if for every $1\le i\le k$ and nonzero $v_1, v_2\dots v_{i-1},v_{i+1}\dots v_k\in V$, the covector that sends $v$ to $f(v_1, v_2\dots v_{i-1},v,v_{i+1}\dots v_k)$ is nonzero.

There are nondegenerate $2$-linear forms on spaces of every finite dimension, but nondegenerate $3$-linear forms exist only on spaces of dimensions $1$, $2$, $4$ and $8$.

**Question 1**. For which $n$ and $k$ there are nondegenerate $k$-forms on $n$-dimensional spaces over $\mathbb{R}$?

My reasoning is following:

Fix a 3-linear form $f$ and an isomorphism $\phi:V^\ast\to V$. 
Define $t':V\times V\to V^\ast$ as $t'(u,v)(w) = f(u, v, w)$ and $t:V\times V\to V^\ast$ as $t(u, v) = \phi(t'(u,v))$.

Now define $m'(v_1,\dots,v_{k-1})$ to be $t(v_1, t(v_2,\dots t(v_{k-2}, v_{k-1})\dots))\in V $ and finally $m(v_1,\dots,v_{k}) = \phi^{-1}(m'(v_1,\dots,v_{k-1}))(v_k)$. All constructed maps are linear in every argument and so $m$ is a $k$-linear form on $V$. I'm not sure $m$ is nondegenerate though.

Conversely, if we have a $k$-linear, where $k>3$, we can fix all arguments to nonzero values and obtain a 3-linear form. This shows that for every $k \ge 3$  there are k-linear forms on spaces of dimensions precisely $1$, $2$, $4$ and $8$ (if we ignore last sentence of previous paragraph).

**Question 2**. Is this reasoning correct? Is $m$ nondegenerate?